# How to target object using a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a `string` to target an `object`

Change `str = "a.b.c"`
To `a.b.c`

## What I have

```js
a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 'working'
    }
  }
}

function go(o, v) {
  console.log(str[v])
}


str = "a.b.c" // reference to an object
go(str, "d")
```

## How it's suppose to work

```js
a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 'working'
    }
  }
}

function go(o, v) {
  console.log(a.b.c[v])
}


str = "a.b.c"
go(str, "d")
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this, anyways? It seams there would be no point, since you can just use Object syntax `a.b.c.d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string on `"."` and then use `reduce()` function on the resulting array to iteratively drill into your object:

```js
var a = {
      b: {
        c: {
          d: 'working'
        }
      }
    };

    function go(o, v) {
      return (o + "." + v).split(".").reduce((y,z) => y[z], this);
    }

    var result = go('a.b.c', 'd');
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a library named `object-path`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path

This way you can access the value via:

```
str = "a.b.c" 
objectPath.get(a, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **eval( )** function

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

```js
a = { b: { c: { d: 'working' } } }

function go(o, v) {
  console.log(eval(str)[v])
}

str = "a.b.c" 
go(str, "d")
```